# How can I check which commits from which branch after merging to master and from where merged that was deleted?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-bash

**Q1)** If in future I want to check from which branch the commits changes (that branch deleted not present), How can I check ?

**Q3)** I have one more problem that problem is when I merged branch to master that content merged, commits also there but that commits from merged branch that now showing for some merged branch , Why ?

I have checked the shown commits using

> $ git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate

I am attaching the ScreenShot.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git will not make a merge if it does not have to. If you merge two branches, but only one has changed, Git will "fast-forward". Instead of merging, it will just move the branch label.

For example, let's say you worked on a branch but did not work on master.

```
A - B [master]
     \
      C - D [feature]
```

Now you `git checkout master` and `git merge feature`. There's nothing to merge, so Git will "fast-forward" master to feature.

```
# git checkout master
# git merge feature

A - B - C - D [master]
              [feature]
```

Commits are not part of a branch. Once you `git branch -d feature` there is no evidence C and D were written on a different branch.

To avoid this, use `git merge --no-ff` (no fast-foward). This will force Git to make a merge commit even if it doesn't need to.

```
# git checkout master
# git merge --no-ff feature

A - B ------ M[master]
     \     /
      C - D [feature]
```

Comment: **git merge --no-ff** is this helpful command  than **git merge feature** to keep record the changes comes from the branch ?

Comment: @AadityaBurujwale Yes. It is `git merge --no-ff <the branch you want to merge>`. So `git merge --no-ff feature` will ensure that feature is merged, never fast-forwarded.